# InfoPath 2010 in the SP 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath

I have some InfoPath forms that I create it in the SP 2010 environment and these forms work very well in the SP 2010.

I tried to upload it to SP 2016 farm. they didn't work.

I got this error:

Error loading form code assembly: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..

What do you think guys? Should I compile these form in the SP 2016 environment?

---

I republish my form using InfoPath 2013 and SP 2016. It was in my Dev environment.

However, when I try to upload it in the SP 2016 UAT it doesn't work

I cannot install InfoPath in the UAT/PROD environment.

Is there any way to register the dll in the GAC? or it is not the problem?

Answer (score 3):

have you tried by using InfoPath Designer 2013? It should solve your problem. 
Just open the infopath form in Infooath Designer 2013 and publish it into ur site (sp2016).

Comment: Do we need to have Infopath Designer on SP farm server? We can not install Infopath on SP Server. On my dev machine I have Infopath Designer 2013 and I am publishing it to Sp2016 successfully. But When I upload the form template in central admin its failing and giving error    " Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.InfoPath, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' "

Answer (score 1):

You should update the form to use InfoPath 2013 and re-publish it to SharePoint 2016.

Comment: When I open the form in Infopath designer 2013, In programming -> Target Version there is only 2 option Infopath 2010 and InfoPath 2007. Then how can I update the form to use InfoPath 2013 .

Answer (score 0):

Solution has been posted already so I wont cover it again. However I highly recommend migrating to .net forms or consider a 3rd party solution such as Nintex or K2. Infopath is facing its end of life in SharePoint. Personally it's more trouble than its worth.